# Solving for the derivative of y'' - Mistake in Textbook?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am reading "A First Course in Differential Equations with Modeling Applications 11th Edition" by Dennis G. Zill, and the following is presented in the first chapter:

[image]

Is this correct? Shouldn't $y'' = y' - 6$ ? If not, why?

Comment: My guess is the typo is in the first part.  I expect they meant to write $y''-y'+6y=0$.  Otherwise, it is really a first order equation in disguise.

Comment: Seems a pretty strange approach,  considering the L.H.S. is easy to solve as a homogeneous equation with constant coefficients (assuming the typo from above).   If not the typo, then $y''-y'=6$ is is a first order D.E. n $y'$, also an easier form...